# Rails: Conditional statement with && and ||

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I currently have this:

```
<% if h.ab_template.AB_filterParent == 0 && h.status != 'geo_enabled' %>
```

What I'd like to do is say whether if h.ab_template.AB_filterParent == 0 || nil. How would I do that?

I tried this but it wasn't working:

```
    <% if (h.ab_template.AB_filterParent == 0 || nil) && h.status != 'geo_enabled' %>
```

Would love to know what I've mistyped or implemented incorrectly!

Cheers

Comment: `h.ab_template.AB_filterParent.to_i == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `h.ab_template.AB_filterParent` will always be a number (can be wrapped by quotes), then you can try following

```
<% if h.ab_template.AB_filterParent.to_i == 0 && h.status != 'geo_enabled' %>
```

else, if there is a possibility that `h.ab_template.AB_filterParent` can be something like *"abc"*, *"0asd"* etc then try:

```
<% if (h.ab_template.AB_filterParent.nil? || h.ab_template.AB_filterParent == 0) && h.status != 'geo_enabled' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally nil and zero shouldn't mean the same thing. Try to eliminate the possibility of AB_filterParent being nil before you hit this code, by assigning a default value of zero in your migration table. I don't know how your model is so I can't even show an example of how to do it. 
The main problem of using `to_i ==` 0 is that it only works if AB_filterParent is either an integer or nil.

```
0.5.to_i == 0
"asdasd".to_i == 0
```

So it's odd.

Another way is to have it initialized in an action or other model method or even after_create callback.